# Simple binomial coefficients sum question

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I know $\sum_\limits{i=0}^n \dbinom{n}{i}=2^n$, and some others, but is there a simple expression when the lower and upper limits are arbitrary, i.e.;

$$\sum_\limits{i=\alpha}^\beta \dbinom{n}{i}=f(\alpha,\beta,n)$$

?

Comment: If you like hypergeometric functions the answer is affirmative, otherwise not. It is more or less the same as asking if $e^{-x^2}$ has a nice primitive, if you consider that the binomial distribution is approximated by the normal distribution.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio; i just thought there would be something easier

Comment: Our world is cruel, sometimes :D